# Add an icon for input type submit using IcoMoon

Tags: html, css, font-face

I am trying to add a search icon into `<input type="submit">` by using IcoMoon. I can't include `<i>` inside `<input>`.

I tried following method of using pseudo elemnt `:before`, but doesn't work.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="top-search">
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
        <input type="submit" class="icon-search" value="e90e">
    </form>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    src: url('icomoon.eot?lkqd5y');
    src: url('icomoon.eot?lkqd5y#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('icomoon.ttf?lkqd5y') format('truetype'),
         url('icomoon.woff?lkqd5y') format('woff'),
         url('icomoon.svg?lkqd5y#icomoon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
    font-family: 'icomoon' !important;
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.icon-search:before {
    content: "\e90e";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i found solution to above question

```
<input type="submit" class="icon-search" value="&#xe90e">
```

Answer (score 2):

`<input>` element doesn't allow to have pseudo content. You can use `<button type="submit">` instead. So that you can either use `:before` or add `<i>` tag into it directly.

Comment: but finally i found this `<input type="submit" class="icon-search" value="&#xe90e">` and it works

Comment: Yes, that could be another way to do it, the point is you can't use pseudo elements on input tag.

Comment: yeai need to know above can be used or ?? because i don't find any other method

Comment: I think the way it works is because the browser simply renders `&#xe90e` as an icon character, as it has a `icon-search` class, which sets the `font-family` to icomoon. It doesn't use any pseudo element in that case.